# Swift + C functions

Tags: c, swift, swift2

I have the following C function

```
struct answer* create(struct callbacks *callbacks);
```

I need to create a struct of function pointers and call this function from Swift

What I have so far is:

```
func aa(state: CInt, user_data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {}
func bb(state: CInt, user_data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {}
struct CallbacksStruct {
     let on_aa = aa
     let on_bb = bb
}
```

and I try to call the function like this:

```
var callbackStruct = CallbacksStruct()
let ans = create(&callbackStruct)
```

but, without any success

Is it even possible in Swift ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. In Swift 2, one can send a Swift closure as a parameter to C, when C expects a function pointer. In your case, you have wrapped it in a struct, so an addition of '**@convention(c)**' to explicitly state that it's C, might help.

see examples here
[new-conventionc-in-swift-2-how-can-i-use-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740560/new-conventionc-in-swift-2-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: Thanks!
didn't check it yet, but seems right. Will update.