# How to make a callback function pointer from C++ to Swift?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

There are many tutorials to make this on web but none are clear and objective, because thats I'm prefer show my case.

I'm developing a iOS app that use a C API to connect to a service web and it have callback functions, my task is simple, I must get events generateds in C code on Swift code. To this I tried some ways, the current way that I'm trying is the follow.

**Scenario**

I've three files: `wrapper.cpp`, `Bridging-Header.h` and `ViewController.swift`

On `Briding-Header.h` I declared a function's pointer.

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
void callback_t(void(*f)(unsigned char*));
```

On `wrapper.cpp` I wrote my code to connect to web and use callback functions. So this is the callback method to get state connection when is disconnected.

**wrapper.cpp**

```
void callback_web_disconnected(unsigned char *c) {
    printf("Disconnected %s",c);
    // Here I want invoke a method to Swift code
    callback_t(r); // But this not works
}
```

It's not compiles, error message: `Use of undeclared identifier 'callback_t'`.

If I try write: `void callback_frame(unsigned char*);`, `linker command failed with exit code 1` error occurs.

**ViewController.swift**

```
func callback_t(_ f: ((UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?) -> Void)!) {
        print("ARRIVED ON VIEWCONTROLLER!")
        // Here I want get the error code (unsigned char*) passed as parameter
    }
```

I can't import `Bridging-Header.h` file on `wrapper.cpp` because cause many conflicts.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746414/7831758 about using convention(c) and passing closures to C functions

Comment: @Augusto did you manage to find a perfect solution, I am facing the same problem, can share your solution?

Comment: @ZainAli look it: https://github.com/ademar111190/CppAndroidIosExample

Answer (score 6):

First, `callback_t` is not an identifier. I don't see it `typedef` anywhere..
Second, you need some way of telling C++ that the callback is your swift function. To do that, I pass it as a parameter to the C++ function similar to how we do it in Objective-C and Swift.. Otherwise you need to store the callback in a global variable somewhere and have C++ access it.

Using the first method of passing the callback as a parameter:

First in the C++ header (`Foo.h`) I did (Do NOT remove the `ifdef` stuff.. the compiler uses C linkage when importing to Swift but when compiling the C++ side, it'll be mangled so to make it use C linkage, we `extern "C"` the code):

```
#ifndef Foo_hpp
#define Foo_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef void(*callback_t)(const char *);
    void callback_web_disconnected(callback_t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif /* Foo_hpp */
```

Then in the implementation file (`Foo.cpp`) I did:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void callback_web_disconnected(callback_t callback)
    {
        std::thread t = std::thread([callback] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

            if (callback)
            {
                callback("Hello World");
            }
        });

        t.detach();
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

Then in ViewController.swift I did:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        callback_web_disconnected({
            if let ptr = $0 {
                let str = String(cString: ptr)
                print(str)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It works fine. The Swift code gets called from C++ after 2 seconds has passed.

---

Using the second method of storing the callback in a global variable (which I despise but let's not get into that)..

In `Foo.h` I did:

```
#ifndef Foo_hpp
#define Foo_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef void(*callback_t)(const char *);
    callback_t globalCallback; //Declare a global variable..

    void callback_web_disconnected();

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif /* Foo_hpp */
```

In `Foo.cpp` I did:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void callback_web_disconnected()
    {
        std::thread t = std::thread([] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

            if (globalCallback)
            {
                globalCallback("Hello World");
            }
        });

        t.detach();
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

In `ViewController.swift`, I did:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Set the globalCallback variable to some block or function we want to be called..

        globalCallback = {
            if let ptr = $0 {
                let str = String(cString: ptr)
                print(str)
            }
        }

        //Trigger our test.. I guess your C++ code will be doing this anyway and it'll call the globalCallback.. but for the sake of this example, I've done it here..
        callback_web_disconnected()
    }
}
```

Comment: On the both options, when I try write the closure in .swift file the follow error occurs: `Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type 'callback_t?' (aka 'Optional<@convention(c) (Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>) -> ()>')`

Comment: `callback_t` has an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` argument.. but you're assigning a closure that has no arguments.. perhaps try: `let meh = callback_t = { (UnsafePointer<Int8>) in }` and then assign `meh` or pass `meh` as the parameter.